# reference needed in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

I believe I have a proof of the following result, which I need as a lemma. Indeed I have seen oblique references to this result using Google.  But I would prefer a specific citation. Can anyone provide one?

> **Lemma:**  Suppose that $f$ is continuous and non-decreasing in $[0,1]$. Then $f$ can be 
>   uniformly approximated by functions which are non-decreasing and absolutely continuous.

Comment: Can you just say "obvious"? Don't seem that it is easy to find a book which have this specific result.

Comment: Do you think it is obvious for the Cantor function?  I would hesitate to assume this; would all referees let it by?

Comment: @spheh Doesn't $f$ itself satisfies the requirement?

Comment: @JohnZHANG The Cantor function is continuous and nondecreasing but not absolutely continuous.

Comment: @angryavian I see. Thanks!

Comment: @spheh: I think it is obvious that $f$ can be approximate by pievewise linear nondecreasing function.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f_n$ be defined by $f_n(x)= n\left(f\left(\frac{k+1}{n}\right)-f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)\left(x-\frac{k}{n}\right)+f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)$ for $k=\lfloor nx\rfloor$ (i.e. each $\text{ }f_n$ is a continuous piecewise-linear approximation of $\text{ }f$). Then $\text{ }f_n$ is differentiable a.e., the derivative is Lebesgue integrable (because it is a step function), and $$f_n(0)+\int_0^xf^{\prime}_n(t)dt=f_n(0)+\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor nx\rfloor-1}\int_{\frac{k}{n}}^{\frac{k+1}{n}}f^{\prime}_n(t)dt+\int_{\frac{\lfloor nx\rfloor}{n}}^xf^{\prime}_n(t)dt\\=f_n(0)+\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor nx\rfloor-1}\left(f\left(\frac{k+1}{n}\right)-f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)+n\left(f\left(\frac{\lfloor nx\rfloor+1}{n}\right)-f\left(\frac{\lfloor nx\rfloor}{n}\right)\right)\left(x-\frac{\lfloor nx\rfloor}{n}\right)\\ = n\left(f\left(\frac{\lfloor nx\rfloor+1}{n}\right)-f\left(\frac{\lfloor nx\rfloor}{n}\right)\right)\left(x-\frac{\lfloor nx\rfloor}{n}\right)+f\left(\frac{\lfloor nx\rfloor}{n}\right)=f_n(x)$$

Finally, we will use the fact that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$. Let $\epsilon>0$ and $\delta>0$ such that $\vert x-y\vert<\delta$ implies $\vert f(x)-f(y)\vert<\epsilon$ for every $x,y$.
$$\vert f_n(x)-f(x)\vert=\left\vert\left[ f_n(x)-f\left(\frac{\lfloor nx\rfloor}{n}\right)\right]+\left[f\left(\frac{\lfloor nx\rfloor}{n}\right)-f(x)\right]\right\vert\\\leq\epsilon+\epsilon=2\epsilon\text{ if $n>\frac{1}{\delta}$, regardless of $x$}$$
Thus the sequence $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $[0,1]$, and each $f_n$ is absolutely continuous and non-decreasing.

Comment: In particular, this works for the Cantor function. ;-)

Comment: The idea of my proof is: Approximate $f$ by a polynomial $p$. Then let $F(x) = sup_{0<=s<=x} p(s)$.  A little fiddling is necesssary at the end points, but essentially $F$ is as close

Comment: (Since to me "piecewise linear" means a finite number of non-differentiable points, and the Cantor function has uncountably many, it doesn't seem obvious.)

Comment: "Any continuous function on $[0,1]$ can be uniformly approximated by a piecewise linear function." This is an exercise that many students do as undergrads (myself included), and I have given a succinct proof of it above. I think this may be related to John saying that this is "obvious."

The $f_n$ *do* only have a finite number of non-differentiable points each, but the number of points of differentiability is irrelevant to uniform convergence, hence the nastiness of the Cantor function cannot let it escape being a uniformly continuous function.

Comment: As far as polynomials: in theory they are dense (I mean they literally are), but in practice polynomial approximations oscillate wildly as you increase the degree (without knowing what you're doing). It takes significantly less care to manipulate low degree approximations - hence the motivation for using 1st degree.